# Best practice for handling large sets of documents in MongoDB. Referencing VS Embedding

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, data-modeling

I am working on a webapp at the moment where I intend to store data that looks something like this:

- Organizations

  - Users within such organization

    - Documents under each user

My question is if it would be better to store this data across multiple databases, and reference each data point where it is necessary, or to have one database that stores organizations, then each organization document holds an array of documents of each user, then each user document holds and array of documents. For the first option, I would have a database for organizations, users, and then user data. In the organization file for example, I would store/reference users as documentIDs opposed to their actual documents.

I hope this makes sense, but yea, my question is, which would be a better practice? To spread the data across multiple DBs and reference it, or have each point of data directly store the data it needs to reference.

Thank you!

Comment: MongoDB stores data in databases, collections and documents. Documents have fields and values. To structure data as per your application needs you do data modeling (sometimes called as database design). The design process leads to an optimal structure - that is your goal (I see). The model depends upon the relationships between entities, amount of data and the kind of important operations (or crud) you intend to perform on the data. These are some main considerations.

Comment: ...Continued from previous note : Here is a reference for more information: [MongoDB Data Model Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: Using mulitple databases would be a poor design. Many operation (e.g. [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)) do not work across several databases.  But perhaps you are mixing the terms, please get familiar with them first.